# OpenERP - OpenChatter and track_visibility fields datetime

Tags: python, odoo, utc, openerp-7

I understand that with 'track_visibility' can generate a kind of log of changes in value, this works very well, but I've found problems with my time zone and datetime fields; as the value showing me is the UTC-0 and my time zone is UTC-5.

```
an Example
2015-17-31 18:25:42 → 2015-17-31 19:25:42 
In OpenChatter session shows:
2015-07-31 23:25:42 → 2015-08-01 00:25:42
```

I tried to correct this by overriding the method  message_track of convert_for_display (*mail_thread*) but I can not do it, because they are not as override a method that is inside another method.

```
def message_track(self, cr, uid, ids, tracked_fields, initial_values, context=None):
    ## How do I access method def convert_for_display (value, col_info)?
    super(citamedica, self).message_track(cr, uid, ids, tracked_fields, initial_values, context=context)
    return True
```

If someone could guide me it would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You no need to override that method. You can handle with simple this trick.

On *datetime* field add below attribute on *.py side*

```
track_visibility='always'
```

With this attribute will post a chatter log whenever field is change it's value.

Comment: thanks for replying, my problem is that datetime fields are displayed in the log incorrectly, if the change was for example 2015-17-31 18:25:42 to 2015-17-31 19:25:42 appears to log 2015-07-31 23:25:42 to 2015-08-01 00:25:42. 5 Hours difference I associate with my time zone UTC-5, apparently it does not take into account the user's time zone for OpenChatter.